# Can’t find C Terminal Burnham Series ES2

Tags: thermostat-c-wire, nest

Try to install Nest thermostat 3rd gen. I have 3 wires coming from the furnace: R, W, and G. I connected them to Nest pretty simple there, but low battery, Wi-Fi not working on a daily basis. There is no C wire. Checked my HVAC, it has 3 wires as well, the green was not connected when I opened it. I was thinking to connect it to terminal 3 and moved the G wire to C on the Nest, outside unit is on and off every 5 seconds. I changed it back to prevent damages. How to add a C wire? Do I use an adapter? I used to have 2nd gen and it works great without C wire. Now my Nest voltage is at around 3.8 and lin is at 20mA.

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and add some pics (or upload them to somewhere like imgur and share the link).

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring diagram for your boiler please?

Answer (score 0):

You have C in your system, just maybe not conected to the thermostat.

Trace it

Find the 24 Volt transformer in the HVAC unit.

One side is hot 24 Volt. The other side is C.

That one needs to go to thermostat C.

Comment: I measured from terminal 3 to next T terminal, showed 26V. Not sure why using G wire as C not working. Frustrating. Condenser is going on and off, sounds like not enough power going through.

Comment: @Mike G is for fan control, it is not C

Comment: @Mike what is terminal 3 and T